# RecyclerView item's image bug

Tags: java, android, xml, jvm, kotlin

**Problem: Glitch bug with RecyclerView's child's item ImageView**

I have a RecyclerView.Each item has ImageView with id "like" which is basically an empty star.

When we click on some item's "Like", for example, the first, the star is changing from empty filled in yellow, which means that item is liked.

When we click on the first item everything is OK, everything is as it should be, but at the same time, we have a bug, changing the sixth item's "like" to a filled star, which shouldn't be done, as this item wasn't liked yet.

*If we click on second item's like - the seventh item would have the same bug.*

**To fill the item's in ViewHolder I have a model - Recipe.**

```
open class Recipe constructor(open var label: String,

                          open var image: String,

                          open var url: String,

                          open var ingredients: RealmList<Ingredient>?,

                          open var calories: Float,

                          open var totalWeight: Float,

                          open var id: Int,

                          open var isFavorite: Boolean) : RealmObject()
```

So when clicking on some item I check whether it isFavorite or not, and change the "like" ImageView accordingly.

Have anyone got any ideas how I should fix this?

I tried to turn off recycling of items in the adapter, but unfortunately, in this case, the "liked" state isn't saved too.

**OnClick listener for "like" button**

```
itemView.like.onClick {
                if (recipe.isFavorite) {
                    itemView.like.image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context, R.drawable.ic_star_before_like)
                    recipe.isFavorite = false
                    DatabaseService.removeRecipeFromFavorites(recipe)
                    itemView.context.toast("Recipe removed from favorites.")
                } else {
                    itemView.like.image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context, R.drawable.ic_star_after_like)
                    recipe.isFavorite = true
                    DatabaseService.addNewFavoriteRecipe(recipe)
                    itemView.context.toast("Recipe added to favorites.")
                }

            }
```

**XML-File**

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dip"
  android:layout_weight="0.8"
  android:gravity="center|right"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/like"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size_card"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size_card"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/icon_margin_card"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_star_before_like" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size_card"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size_card"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/icon_margin_card"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_share" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/save"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size_card"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size_card"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/icon_margin_card"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_save_recipe" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/expand"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size_card"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size_card"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/icon_margin_card"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_down_arrow" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RecyclerView` reuses the viewholders it creates with `onCreateViewHolder`. To put it simply, think of it as the views going off screen on the top coming back around on the bottom, and vica versa. Therefore, the nice way of solving what you want is the following:

1. Set the icon to the right drawable in the `onBindViewHolder` method. This way, whether a viewholder is being bound for the first time, or had a drawable reflecting a recipe's favourited state already, it will be refreshed properly.

   Without knowing what your adapter looks like, this should give you an idea of how to do this (the example code assumes you have your recipes in some list called `recipes`):

   ```
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
       val recipe = recipes[position]
       val itemView = holder.itemView
       itemView.like.image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(itemView.context,
               if(recipe.isFavorite) R.drawable.ic_star_before_like else R.drawable.ic_star_after_like)
   }
   ```
2. In the listener, modify the `Recipe` the same way you're doing it now, but instead of then setting the image directly, notify the adapter that the recipe at the given position has changed ([`notifyItemChanged(position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int))), which will make it re-bind that item, refreshing the icon to reflect the new state. Again, I don't know where you're setting up the listener, but I assume you know what position the recipe is at in the list there.

Answer (score 2):

`RecyclerView` is built to cache views and reuse them. When you scroll, your views are recycled and loaded from the memory.

After you have made changes to your underlying data model attached to the adapter, it is important to notify the adapter about the same. In your `onClick` method, after you've made the changes, make sure you call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` or just `notifyDataSetChanged()` if you're calling it directly from your adapter class.

Comment: Your answer was right as well, but the second one has code sample and would be more appreciate by the community. 
Thank you a lot! You were right and you saved me hours, I guess :)